# Pandas: add new row to Multi index table does not work

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a weird problem: I am trying to add a new row in my table with multi-indeces. However, even though I do it exactly as solved in here: [adding a row to a MultiIndex DataFrame/Series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24917700/2156909) . Their example and solution works, but it does not work with my data. Either I am doing something wrong, or there is a bug

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
```

Their code (working):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [dt.datetime(2013,2,3,9,0,1), dt.datetime(2013,2,3,9,0,1)], 
                   'hsec': [1,25], 'vals': [45,46]})
df.set_index(['Time','hsec'],inplace=True)

print df
df.ix[(dt.datetime(2013,2,3,9,0,2),0),:] = 5
print df
```

Output:

```
                          vals
Time                hsec      
2013-02-03 09:00:01 1       45
                    25      46
```

and

```
                          vals
Time                hsec      
2013-02-03 09:00:01 1       45
                    25      46
2013-02-03 09:00:02 0        5
```

My code (not working):

```
d = [[0, 0, 2], [0, 2, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=('frames', 'classID', 'amount'))
df.set_index(['frames', 'classID'], inplace=True)
print df

df.ix[(1,1),:] = 5
print df
```

Output:

```
                amount
frames classID        
0      0             2
       2             2
1      0             2
       2             2
```

and

```
                amount
frames classID        
0      0             2
       2             5
1      0             2
       2             2
```

Note the `5` appeared at `df.loc[(0,2)]` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a bug in pandas to me, but it is apparantly fixed in the newly released 0.16:

```
In [9]: pd.__version__
Out[9]: '0.16.0'

In [10]: df.ix[(1,1),:] = 5

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                amount
frames classID
0      0             2
       2             2
1      0             2
       2             2
       1             5
```

But I can confirm this was indeed not working in pandas 0.15.2. If can upgrade to pandas 0.16, I would also advice to explicitly use `loc` in this case (so it certainly does not fall back to the positional integer location). But note the bug is also in `loc` below pandas 0.16

Comment: i confirm that the bug is fixed in the version you get with `pip install pandas` i.e. pandas 0.16.0