# Applying new row within second level index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a data frame that looks something like:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|           |         | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 |
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| Product 1 | Revenue |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|           | Cost    |     0 |     0 |     0 |
| Product 2 | Revenue |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|           | Cost    |     0 |     0 |     0 |
| Product 3 | Revenue |     0 |     0 |     0 |
|           | Cost    |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+-----------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Essentially a two level index on the vertical. The first level is the product and the second either revenue or cost.

I would like to add a Profit row to all products below Revenue and Cost (simply Revenue - Cost). Or even the average of that products Revenue etc. However, after much experimentation with apply, I cannot seem to get this to work with the multi levels.

```
Product 1 Revenue    0
          Cost       0
          Profit     0
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: FYI - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/4049396 for tips on how to write a good question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does depend on how many times you want to do this and how your current other values are stored.

If you wish to add just a small number of Profits to each of the above you could use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917700/adding-a-row-to-a-multiindex-dataframe-series). However, this method uses `ix` which is to be deprecated (I believe). Therefore, I would suggest using `at`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'b'): [1, 2, 3], ('A', 'a'): [7, 2, 9]}).T
df.at[('B', 'a'), :] = [1, 4, 5]

Out[1]:     
                0    1   2
         A  b   1    2   3
            a   7    2   9
         B  a   1    4   5
```

If your Profit information is stored in another DataFrame, it would be easiest to use `concat`, like so,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'b'): [1, 2, 3], ('A', 'a'): [7, 2, 9]}).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame({('B', 'a'): [1, 4, 5]}).T

pd.concat([df, df2])

Out[1]: 
        0   1   2
A   b   1   2   3
    a   7   2   9
B   a   1   4   5
```