# python/pandas: DataFrame inheritance and DataFrame update when 'inplace' is not possible

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, inheritance, init

I am sorry, I am aware the title is somewhat fuzzy.

## Context

I am using a `Dataframe` to keep track of files because pandas `DataFrame` features several relevant functions to do all kind of filtering a dict cannot do, with `loc`, `pd.IndexSlice`, `.index`, `.columns`, `pd.MultiIndex`...
Ok, so this may not appear as the best choice for expert developers (which I am not), but all these functions have been so much handy that I have come to use a `DataFrame` for this.
And cherry on the cake, `__repr__` of a MultiIndex `Dataframe` is just perfect when I want to know what is inside my file list.

## Quick introduction to `Summary` class, inheriting from `DataFrame`

Because my `DataFrame`, that I call 'Summary', has some specific functions, I would like to make it a class, inheriting from pandas `DataFrame` class.
It also has 'fixed' MultiIndexes, for both rows and columns.

Finally, because my `Summary` class is defined outside the `Store` class which is actually managing file organization, `Summary` class needs a function from `Store` to be able to retrieve file organization.

## Questions

Trouble with `pd.DataFrame` is (AFAIK) you cannot append rows without creating a new `DataFrame`.
As `Summary` has a `refresh` function so that it can `recreate` itself by reading folder content, a `refresh` somehow 'reset' the 'Summary' object.
To manage `Summary` refresh, I have come up with a first code (not working) and finally a second one (working).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dummy function
def summa(a,b):
    return a+b

# Does not work
class DatF1(pd.DataFrame):

    def __init__(self,meth,data=None):
        cmidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Index', 'Index'],['First', 'Last']])
        rmidx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]], codes=[[],[]],
                              names=['Component','Interval'])
        super().__init__(data=data, index=rmidx, columns=cmidx, dtype=np.datetime64)
        self.meth=meth

    def refresh(self):
        values = [[pd.Timestamp('2020/02/10 8:00'),pd.Timestamp('2020/02/10 8:00')],
                  [pd.Timestamp('2020/02/11 8:00'),pd.Timestamp('2020/02/12 8:00')]]
        rmidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Comp1','Comp1'],['1h','1W']],names=['Component','Interval'])
        self = pd.DataFrame(values, index=rmidx, columns=self.columns)

ex1 = DatF1(summa)

In [10]: ex1.meth(3,4)
Out[10]: 7

ex1.refresh()
In [11]: ex1
Out[11]: Empty DatF1
         Columns: [(Index, First), (Index, Last)]
         Index: []
```

After `refresh()`, `ex1` is still empty. `refresh` has not worked correctly.

```
# Works
class DatF2(pd.DataFrame):

    def __init__(self,meth,data=None):
        cmidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Index', 'Index'],['First', 'Last']])
        rmidx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]], codes=[[],[]],
                              names=['Component','Interval'])
        super().__init__(data=data, index=rmidx, columns=cmidx, dtype=np.datetime64)
        self.meth=meth

    def refresh(self):
        values = [[pd.Timestamp('2020/02/10 8:00'),pd.Timestamp('2020/02/10 8:00')],
                  [pd.Timestamp('2020/02/11 8:00'),pd.Timestamp('2020/02/12 8:00')]]
        rmidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Comp1','Comp1'],['1h','1W']],names=['Component','Interval'])
        super().__init__(values, index=rmidx, columns=self.columns)

    ex2 = DatF2(summa)

    In [10]: ex2.meth(3,4)
    Out[10]: 7

    ex2.refresh()
    In [11]: ex2
    Out[11]:                                  Index                    
                                              First                Last
             Component Interval                                        
             Comp1     1h       2020-02-10 08:00:00 2020-02-10 08:00:00
                       1W       2020-02-11 08:00:00 2020-02-12 08:00:00
```

This code works!

I have 2 questions:

- why the 1st code is not working? (I am sorry, this is maybe obvious, but I am completely ignorant why it does not work)
- is calling `super().__init__` in my `refresh` method acceptable coding practise? (or rephrased differently: is it acceptable to call `super().__init__` in other places than in `__init__` of my subclass?)

Thanks a lot for your help and advice. The world of class inheritance is for me quite new, and the fact that `DataFrame` content cannot be directly modified, so to say, seems to me to make it a step more difficult to handle.

Have a good day,
Bests,

## Error message when adding a new row

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dummy function
def new_rows():
    return [['Comp1','Comp1'],['1h','1W']]

# Does not work
class DatF1(pd.DataFrame):

    def __init__(self,meth,data=None):
        cmidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Index', 'Index'],['First', 'Last']])
        rmidx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]], codes=[[],[]],
                          names=['Component','Interval'])
        super().__init__(data=data, index=rmidx, columns=cmidx, dtype=np.datetime64)
        self.meth=meth

    def refresh(self):
        values = [[pd.Timestamp('2020/02/10 8:00'),pd.Timestamp('2020/02/10 8:00')],
                  [pd.Timestamp('2020/02/11 8:00'),pd.Timestamp('2020/02/12 8:00')]]
        rmidx = self.meth()
        self[rmidx] = values

ex1 = DatF1(new_rows)
ex1.refresh()

KeyError: "None of [MultiIndex([('Comp1', 'Comp1'),\n            (   '1h',    '1W')],\n           names=['Component', 'Interval'])] are in the [index]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answers to your questions

> why the 1st code is not working?

You are trying to call the class you've inherited from. Honestly, I don't know what's happening exactly in your case. I assumed this would produce an error but you got an empty dataframe.

> is calling `super().__init__` in my refresh method acceptable coding practise?

Maybe a legitimate use case exists for calling `super().__init__` outside the __init__() method. But your case is not one of them. You have already inherited evertyhing from in your __init__() . Why use it again?

---

### A better solution

The solution to your problem is unexpectedly simple. Because you **can** [append a row to a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe):

`df['new_row'] = [value_1, value_2, ...]`

Or in your case with an MultiIndex (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917700/adding-a-row-to-a-multiindex-dataframe-series)):

```py
  df.loc[('1h', '1W'), :] = [pd.Timestamp('2020/02/10 8:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020/02/10 8:00')]
```

---

### Best practice

You should not inherit from pd.DataFrame. If you want to extend pandas use the [documented API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.
Well, I actually tried to append new rows, and I copied-pasted above the code as an addendum. I do not succeed to make it work, and I also show the error message. Do you have any idea about what can be wrong?

Regarding the best practises, thanks a lot. I did not know about them.
Ok, I see I can add methods with this such as the 'refresh' method.
But I could not spot in this documentation where I can format the MultiIndex of my columns and my rows. Do you have any additional pointers maybe?

Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciated!

Comment: Coming back to the "best practise". I have read several times the link you provide. Nowhere I see a way to actually extend a DataFrame with methods that actually modify it, I am sorry. So it does seem I am forced to use inheritance. Please, am I wrong?

Comment: I think you don't need any inheritance or extending of your dataframe at all. The "standard" DataFrame can be changed without the need of a refresh() method. I have updated my answer, because I did not account for the MultiIndex. The syntax is slightly different.